# ABS cellular-core Pipes Safe?

Tags: plumbing

I have some ABS Cellular-Core Pipe for a DIY project. The project is a garden in the pipe. I have been told that this pipe has chemicals that could harm my family when consuming the food. The question is are these ABS cellular-core pipes safe to drink water from and plant plants in?

Answer (score 1):

If the markings on the outside include "NSF-PW" the pipe is rated for potable (drinking) water use. Most "cellular core" pipe won't be so marked, in my experience, since it is only intended for Drain, Waste, Vent (DWV) applications, not drinking water.

I don't know if there's any real hazard to growing plants in them - certainly many plants are grown (or at least started) in plastic pots that are likely not plastic that is rated for eating or drinking from...